# Handle required attributes of parent class(a dataclass) using metaclass or decorators

Tags: python, pydantic, python-dataclasses

Suppose class A has n attributes(uninitialized). Now I want a child class that should not directly initialize the parent attributes but should pass a list to a decorator or a metaclass, where only the passed-in attributes should get initialized and the rest attributes should not complain about TypeError or any sort of error.

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int

# <or via a decorator @make_optional()>
class B(A, <or via a metaclass here>):
    pass
b = B(a=1) # I don't want to initialize b but to handle it as suggested
```

Currently, I am getting the error:

`TypeError: A.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`

I am able to do this via Pydantic <=1.9, but not possible in higher versions of Pydantic or Dataclasses.

Answer (score 1):

But what do you want the resulting instance to use instead of "b" in your example?

As your question is, it looks just a matter of marking field "b" as optional, by writting a default value for it.

Otherwise either a metaclass or decorator will have to fill in a value for "b" in order to call the dataclass-generated `__init__` method, and that value will work as a default. And in that case it will be as good as a default that goes directly in the field declaration!

Or maybe, you may not want the dataclass generated `__init__` to run at all, then, just mark `init=False` in your dataclass call, to start with.

If you want the behavior of dataclass `__init__` and want the attributes to simply do not exist when they are not passed in, you could have a special marker value as the default, and write a **post_init** method that will delete those from the instance - I guess that would suffice for whatever use you have in mind:

```
DELETE_ME = object()
@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int|None = DELETE_ME
    def __post_init__(self, *args, **kw):
        for name, field in self.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            if field.default is DELETE_ME and getattr(self, name, None) is DELETE_ME:
                delattr (self, name)
```

(Or you can just use "None" instead of a DELETE_ME special value, if your intention is that it never holds None, but just doesn't get set at all)

Since you asked, as mentioned above, a class-decorator could be used: it would wrap the `__init__` method created by the `dataclass` decorator - and in order for that method to run (we don't want to re-implement the work of the `__init__` method the dataclass create, so we would call it), the extra decorator would have to inject values for any fields without a provided default (or default factory) - otherwise, it will just break with TypeError. The decorator could inject  a sentinel value (like the `DELETE_ME` above), and remove the field value from the instance upon returning from the `__init__` call. The effect is the same as removing it on the `__post_init__` method - that is why I am not providing this solution in code: your case seems to be covered.